# F# Units of Measure doesn't simplify

Tags: f#, units-of-measurement, simplification

Assume such measures are defined:

```ml
[<Measure>] type kilogram
[<Measure>] type kg = kilogram

[<Measure>] type s
```

When I define a binding like this:

```ml
let x = 1.<kg / kilogram> // Type of x: float
```

F# correctly simplifies type of x from `float<kg/kilogram>` to `float`.
But when I add another unit like this:

```ml
let y = 1.<kg s / kilogram> // Type of y: float<kg s / kilogram>
```

Instead of simplfying type of y to `float<s>`, it shows `float<kg s / kilogram>`

Why doesn't F# simplify it in this case? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see based on a couple of experiments, the only place where the compiler uses the fact that `kg = kilogram` in the simplification process is when the final type is unit-less, i.e. `float<1>` type. In all other cases I tried, it keeps both `kg` and `kilogram` in the unit type.

I suspect the compiler still knows that the type of `1.<kg/kilogram>` is `kg/kilogram`, but because this is equivalent to `1`, it does not display it - it shows `float` rather than `float<1>` or `float<kg/kilogram>`.

It is worht noting that the simplificiation happens when it is actually needed - if you try comparing a value `1.<kg s / kilogram>` with a value `1.<s / 1>`, this is well-typed:

```
let y = 1.<kg s / kilogram>
y = 1.<s/1>
```

I do not have a solid evidence (like a link to the specification), but I think the compiler only does the simplification when it actually has to, but otherwise keeps the unit annotations as you write them.

Comment: This is consistent with other mechanisms that let you create equivalent types, like type abbreviations. If you define `type MyType = string` and then write `let x : MyType = "hello"` it will (intuitively) annotate the type as MyType, pretty much because _that's what you told it to do_. This goes further of course